# Android:Espresso: click is block UI and can't do next check

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I has activity with button. When click this button I show specific layout. 
I want to write Espresso test that check than if press button then show specific layout. 
Here test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AddTraderActivityTest {
    // The IntentsTestRule class initializes Espresso Intents before each test, terminates the host activity, and releases Espresso Intents after each test
    @get:Rule
    var addTraderActivity: IntentsTestRule<AddTraderActivity> = IntentsTestRule(AddTraderActivity::class.java)

@Test
fun allFieldsFill_buttonStart_click_progress_isDisplayed() {
    onView(withId(R.id.baseTextInputEditText))
        .perform(typeText(BASE_TEST))
    onView(withId(R.id.quoteTextInputEditText))
        .perform(typeText(QUOTE_TEST))

    onView(withId(R.id.startButton))
        .perform(click())

    // not execute while not finish click
    onView(withId(R.id.containerProgressBarLayout))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

The problem is when  call `.perform(click())` then next method

```
onView(withId(R.id.containerProgressBarLayout))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

is **not** being called. While work of `click()` is not finish (the click on the button start a HTTP request). After **N** seconds (when the request is finished) then `Espresso` continue execution and evaluate `.check(matches(isDisplayed()`.

But I need to check that my specific layout is shown when clicking on the button.

Here implement of click button. When click button start **ASYNC** http request by Retrofit 2. After finish then call callback method to get result.

```
 public void doClickStart(String base, String quote) {
        isHidekKeyboardLiveData.setValue(true);
        isShowProgressLiveData.setValue(true);
        TransportService.executeTraderOperation(Trader.Operation.CREATE, base.trim(), quote.trim(), new DefaultRestClientCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Response<Void> response) {
                isShowProgressLiveData.setValue(false);
                isForwardToTradersLiveData.setValue(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorResponse errorResponse) {
                isShowProgressLiveData.setValue(false);
                String message = errorResponse.getMessage();
                messageLiveData.setValue(new SingleEvent(message));
            }
        });
    }

public static void executeTraderOperation(Trader.Operation traderOperation, String base, String quote, Callback<Void> callback) {
        TraderMonitorRestClient traderMonitorRestClient = RestClientFactory.createRestClient(TraderMonitorRestClient.class);
        String sender = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "_" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
        String key = DateUtil.getDateAsString(new Date(), "mmHHddMMyyyy");
        Call<Void> call = traderMonitorRestClient.executeTraderOperation(traderOperation.toString().toLowerCase(), base, quote, sender, key);
        // asynchronously
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
```

on my activity I finish current activity when click was finish:

```
 addTraderViewModel.getIsForwardToTradersLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean isForwardToTraders) {
                if (isForwardToTraders) {
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

here result of fail test:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com.myproject.activity.AddTraderActivityTest#allFieldsFill_buttonStart_click_progress_isDisplayed' com.myproject.debug.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.waitForAtLeastOneActivityToBeResumed(RootViewPicker.java:169)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:83)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule.java:77)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:35)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:24)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:10)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:62)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:276)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:268)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error code you posted, your `Activity` is not started for the tests.
Use this code to mock the activity:

```
@get:Rule
var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<YourActivity> =
   ActivityTestRule(YourActivity::class.java)
```

**OR** if you need to pass arguments to that activity, to this:

```
@get:Rule
var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<YourActivity> =
   ActivityTestRule(YourActivity::class.java)

@Test
fun `test activity X`() {
   val intent = Intent()
   intent.putExtra("your_key", "your_value");
   activityRule.launchActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: No. Activity was started. I updated my  post. Problem is that finish click I call finish() method. As result my current activity is destroy. But I need to test WHILE click work to check is show progress.

Comment: That's strange: From the [this resource here](https://github.com/FutureProcessing/AndroidEspressoIdlingResourcePlayground): espresso **DOESN'T** wait for API network calls to be executed.

Comment: Are you by any chances using this code: `.setExecutors(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new MainThreadExecutor())`?

Comment: No. I use Retrotif 2 to do async work. And it's work nice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191907/discussion-between-luca-nicoletti-and-alexei).